# How to insert rows to an existing table with every click of a button

Tags: javascript, html-table, insert, rows

I have the following code:

```
<table id="t1"> 
<tr>
    <td>Text A</td>
    <td>Text B</td>
</tr>
<% int count1 = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) { %>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" id="amount<%=i%>"></td>
    <td><input type="text" id="convertedAmount<%=i%>" readonly></td>
</tr>
<%count1 =i;
}%>
<tr>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="addRow(<%=count1%>)" value="Add Row"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function appendRow(val){
   var tbody = document.getElementById("t1").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
   var row = document.createElement("TR");
   var textA= document.createElement("TD");
   textA.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="amount'+val+'">';
   var textB= document.createElement("TD");
   textB.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="convertedAmount'+val+'" readonly>';
     row.appendChild(textA);
     row.appendChild(textB);
     tbody.appendChild(row);
   }
```

edited---
ok so I've done up to this part thanks to Barmar. so now the question is how do I increase the value of val (continue from preexisting data)

If I were to use this Javascript, it will just add rows with the text.
So how do I add rows to this table with the respective textboxes and even dropdownlist if I were to use it. can it be done with just Javascript or need to work with servlets as well?

Comment: You do it with Javascript.

Comment: @Barmar I tried using the above javascript but it only add text. I'm not sure how to go about in including the textboxes or even dropdownlist in as well. Thnks

Comment: Something like `textA.innerHTML="<INPUT TYPE='text' ...>"`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried that but got error... so i dun think its possible that way.. is there any other way? thnks

Comment: @Barmar I figured that out already thnks for ur help! is there a way for me to increase the val now? thnks

Comment: You need to get all the elements that match the ID pattern, count them, and then add 1 to that to get the next ID number. This would be pretty easier if you used jQuery, doing it with plain Javascript is more work than I'm willing to put in.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not really fimiliar with JQuery.. so how shld i get started? thnks

Answer (score 0):

In the JavaScript function add following line of code...

val = tbody.children.length;

After assignment  of tbody = document.getElementById('t1').......